# PHP form redirect to thanks page

Tags: php, wordpress, submit

I have a custom WP theme that I'm trying to redirect to a thanks page after the form has been verified. I know there are a ton of other questions very similar, but I've tried the "headers" trick and all of the other suggestions, but my page just keeps going back to the contact.php page. Hovering over the submit button (before clicking it) shows mypageURL.com/contact, instead of mypageURL.com/thanks. Here is my code.

```
<?php 
//Verify the email address
function isemail($email) {
    return preg_match('|^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$|i', $email);
}
//set variables
$error_name = false;
$error_email = false;
$error_message = false;
//Get form values
if (isset($_POST['contact-submit'])) {
    $contact_name = '';
    $contact_email = '';
    $contact_subject = '';
    $contact_message = '';
    $contact_reciever = '';

    if (trim($_POST['contact_name']) === '') {
        $error_name = true;
    } else {
        $contact_name = trim($_POST['contact_name']);
    }

    if (trim($_POST['contact_email']) === '' || !isemail(trim($_POST['contact_email']))) {
        $error_email = true;
    } else {
        $contact_email = trim($_POST['contact_email']);
    }

    $subject = trim($_POST['contact_subject']);

    if (trim($_POST['contact_message']) === '') {
        $error_message = true;
    } else {
        $contact_message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['contact_message']));
    }

    //Check for errors
    if (!$error_name && !$error_email && !$error_message) {
        //Get reciever email
        if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_form_mail' ) != '') $get_contact_reciever = get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_form_mail' ) ;
        $contact_reciever = $get_contact_reciever;

        $the_subject = 'New message: ' . $contact_subject;
        $the_message = 'Message from: ' . $contact_name . PHP_EOL . 'Email: ' . $contact_email . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $contact_message . PHP_EOL ;

        $the_headers = "Form " . $contact_email . PHP_EOL . 'Reply-To: ' . $contact_email . PHP_EOL . 'MIME-Version: 1.0'  . PHP_EOL . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'  . PHP_EOL . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'  . PHP_EOL;

        if (mail($contact_reciever, $the_subject, $the_message, $the_headers)) {
            $contact_form_sent = true;
        } else {
            $contact_form_sent_error = true;
        }
    } else {
        $contact_form_not_filled = true;
    }
}

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="white-section contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID))
                        edit_post_link( $link = __('You are logged in as an Administrator. Click this text to edit this page. This text will not show up if you are not logged in as Admin.', 'cht'), $before = '<i class="icon-edit"></i> ', $after = '' );
                    ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <h4><?php _e('Contact info', 'cht') ?></h4>
                            <ul>
                            <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_name' ) != '') { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_name' ) ?></li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Cloud Hoster Ltd.</li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_address' ) != '') { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_address' ) ?></li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> 01234 Main Street, New York 45678</li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_phone' ) != '') { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-phone"></i> <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_phone' ) ?></li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-phone"></i> Phone: 555-555-5555 Fax: 444-444-4444</li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_mail' ) != '') { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Email: <a href="mailto:<?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_mail' ) ?>"><?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_info_mail' ) ?></a></li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <li><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Email: <a href="mailto:info@domain.com">info@domain.com</a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- span6 end -->

                        <div class="span6">
                            <div id="map"></div>
                                <script>
                                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                                    var map;
                                    map = new GMaps({
                                        div: '#map',
                                        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lat' ) != '') { ?>
                                            lat: <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lat' ) ?>,
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            lat: 40.714353,
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lng' ) != '') { ?>
                                            lng: <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lng' ) ?>,
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            lng: -74.005973,
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        zoom: 15,
                                        zoomControl: true,
                                        zoomControlOpt: {
                                            style : 'SMALL',
                                            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
                                        },
                                        streetViewControl: false,
                                    });

                                    map.addMarker({
                                        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lat' ) != '') { ?>
                                            lat: <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lat' ) ?>,
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            lat: 40.714353,
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lng' ) != '') { ?>
                                            lng: <?php print get_theme_mod( 'custom_google_map_lng' ) ?>,
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            lng: -74.005973,
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    });
                                });
                                </script>
                        </div><!-- span6 end -->
                    </div><!-- row end -->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method='post' name='contactform' id='contactform'>
                                <p><?php _e('Your name:', 'cht') ?></p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="contact_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contact_name'])) echo $_POST['contact_name']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Please enter your name.', 'cht') ?>">
                                <p><?php _e('Email address:', 'cht') ?></p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="contact_email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contact_email'])) echo $_POST['contact_email']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Please enter your email address.', 'cht') ?>">
                                <p><?php _e('What kind of problems are you having?', 'cht') ?></p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="contact_subject" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contact_subject'])) echo $_POST['contact_subject']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Purpose of this message.', 'cht') ?>">
                                <p class="right-message-box"><?php _e('How Can We Help You?', 'cht') ?></p>
                                <textarea class="input-box right-message-box message-box" name="contact_message" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contact_message'])) echo stripslashes($_POST['contact_message']); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Your message.', 'cht') ?>"></textarea>
                                <button type='submit' class='submit-contact-form' name='submit' id="submit">Send your message</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="contact-submit" id="contact-submit" value="true">
                            </form>
                        </div><!-- span12 end -->                   
                    </div><!-- row end -->

                        <?php if (isset($contact_form_sent) && $contact_form_sent == true) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success"><p><strong><?php _e('Success! ', 'cht') ?> </strong><?php _e('Your message has been sent.', 'cht') ?></p></div>
                        <?php elseif (isset($contact_form_sent_error) && $contact_form_sent_error == true) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-error"><p><strong><?php _e('Error! ', 'cht') ?> </strong><?php _e('Something went wrong. Please try again.', 'cht') ?></p></div>
                        <?php elseif (isset($contact_form_not_filled) && $contact_form_not_filled == true) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-error"><p><strong><?php _e('Error! ', 'cht') ?> </strong><?php _e('Fill out the form correctly and try again.', 'cht') ?></p></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- span12 end -->
            </div><!-- row end -->
        </div><!-- conteiner end -->
    </div><!-- white-section end -->

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</section><!-- content end -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a trick, its how you can do exactly what you want done.

```
if (mail($contact_reciever, $the_subject, $the_message, $the_headers)) {
    $contact_form_sent = true;
    header("Location: " . get_permalink($THANKYOU_PAGE_ID));
}
```

Does it throw off any errors when you try using header? If so you might have to create a hook and verify the form earlier in the page load.

I'm assuming your comment means "Yes it is throwing off errors, how do I hook my form earlier so that it doesn't do that?". Well my good friend follow me..

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'form_verify' );
function form_verify() {
    // add form code here with header code
}
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /directory/page-contact.php:7) in /directory/page-contact.php on line 168